# Using three.js, how to integrate EffectComposer with OculusRiftEffect, VREffect or VRRenderer?

Tags: javascript, three.js, oculus, virtual-reality, webvr

Using **three.js**, the classes **OculusRiftEffect**, **VREffect** or **VRRenderer** allow a programmer to render their scene to an Oculus Rift.

**EffectComposer** is another **three.js** class that lets the programmer compose multiple different scenes to be displayed by single renderer.

My question is, how can I display the composed output of **EffectComposer** with the Rift?

The problem is as follows:

The **OculusRiftEffect**, **VREffect** or **VRRenderer** class must be initialised with a renderer such as **WebGLRenderer**. In the render loop, the class must be called as follows, causing the scene to be displayed on the Rift:

```
this.vrrenderer.render(this.threeScene, this.camera);
```

The **EffectComposer** must also be initialised with a renderer such as **WebGLRenderer**. In the render loop, the **EffectComposer** must be called as follows, causing the composed scene to be displayed by the renderer:

```
this.composer.render();
```

However, the **EffectComposer** can't be initialised with an **OculusRiftEffect**, **VREffect** or **VRRenderer** in place of the **WebGLRenderer**.

The question is how to connect the **EffectComposer** to one of the Rift classes for rendering?

Many thanks!

Comment: reddit thread on the same topic: http://www.reddit.com/r/threejs/comments/351pdu/composing_vreffect_with_effectcomposer/

Answer (score 1):

I was able to integrate EffectComposer with StereoEffect, altering it to a new class called StereoCamera. See here for a similar question answered:

[Three.js combining StereoEffect with FXAA ShaderPass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31248397/three-js-combining-stereoeffect-with-fxaa-shaderpass/35120643#35120643)